# Creating a Singleton base class in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, singleton

Straight to the point:
I've got two singleton classes, both inheriting their singleton nature from a super-class. I initialize some properties on the first singleton, and then have the second singleton retrieve **the** instance of the first one. That instance, however, does not seem to be the one I initialized in the first place. Some example code might help to explain this:

First, the super-class, providing singleton nature (requires PHP 5.3 or greater):

```
class Singleton {

    protected static $instance;

    protected function __construct() { }

    final private function __clone() { }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!(static::$instance instanceof static)) {
            static::$instance = new static();
        }
        return static::$instance;
    }

}
```

Then we've got the the first singleton carrying a value:

```
require_once('Singleton.php');

class SingletonA extends Singleton {

    protected $value;

    public function SingletonA() {
        $this->value = false;
    }

    public function getValue() {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

}
```

Then the second singleton that references the first singleton:

```
require_once('Singleton.php');
require_once('SingletonA.php');

class SingletonB extends Singleton {

    public function getValue() {
        return SingletonA::getInstance()->getValue();
    }

}
```

Now for the test that shows how this fails:

```
require_once('SingletonA.php');
require_once('SingletonB.php');

SingletonA::getInstance()->setValue(true);

echo (SingletonA::getInstance()->getValue()) ? "true\n" : "false\n";
echo (SingletonB::getInstance()->getValue()) ? "true\n" : "false\n";
```

The test yields the following output:

```
true
false
```

Clearly, the SingletonA instance that the test code references is not the same instance that the SingletonB instance references. In short, SingletonA is not as single as I need it to be. How is this possible? And what magic can I wield to remedy this behaviour, giving me a true singleton?

Comment: It the first time I've ever encountered inherited Singleton behaviour. Whether or not it's syntactically correct, it's pretty weird.

Comment: A SingletonA will never be an instance of SingletonB, even though they are both Singletons; the `static` keyword will make sure of that.

Comment: Why not just use a Singleton?

Comment: Right, I don't think I managed to communicate this clearly enough. I do not expect SingletonA and SingletonB to be one and the same instance. Quite the opposite, they are two distinct instances of two distinct types. They do share a common ancestor, making them both Singleton types, but that's not the type the test code retrieves. I want the test code to set a field value in SingletonA, then I want SingletonB (which is a different instance and type, completely) to retrieve the SingletonA instance and be able to retrieve the value of its field.

Comment: @spender: Why is it weird? I'm working on a project requiering at least 10 different singleton classes. Why write the same code 10 times over?

Comment: Are you sure you really need 10 different singletons? That's the kind of thing that produces hard to debug/test problems like the one you have here. If you passed an instance of A as a parameter to the constructor of B (and A and B were not singletons) you wouldn't have had this problem in the first place.

Comment: @rojoca I'll admit this is on an experimental stage, but the idea behind this architecture is to use manager classes, implemented as singletons, for dealing with databases, file systems, e-mail and so on. Most manager classes will rely on access to a database, which the database manager supplies them with. By implementing the database manager as a singleton, it can be configured once during "startup", and all classes needing database access can simply call on the database manager class, without having to provide it with the configuration it needs. The same thing goes with the e-mail manager.

Comment: @johan. I started to write a comment, but ran out of room, so I've written my response as an answer.

Comment: @Johan I have renamed the question to make it easier to find for other people with similar problems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using `isset` rather than `instanceof`:

```
class Singleton {
    protected static $instances;

    protected function __construct() { }

    final private function __clone() { }

    public static function getInstance() {
        $class = get_called_class();

        if (!isset(self::$instances[$class])) {
            self::$instances[$class] = new $class;
        }
        return self::$instances[$class];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks lonesomeday, but that gives me the same instance, which is not what I want.

Comment: @Johan You're right, it does. Sorry about that.  I have rewritten your class using an array of instances in `Singleton::$instances`, which does work.

Comment: Thanks a million, man! This version will even run on PHP versions < 5.3, as far as I can see. But I still don't understand why it didn't work.

Comment: It won't work pre 5.3, because `get_called_class` was introduced along with `static` in 5.3. And I'm not sure exactly what the problem was either!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's because you are using static methods, which are not instanced.

Answer (score 0):

`SingletonA` and `SingletonB` are different classes.  Although they inherit from the same class, they are separate classes and so they have different static instances.

If you change your code to get 2 instances of `SingletonA` or 2 instances of `SingletonB`, you will see the behavior you expect.  But because they are different classes, they are not the same singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk OO. :)

`SingletonA` and `SingletonB` are of type `Singleton`

thus it can be said:

> `SingletonA` **is** `Singleton`
>
> *and*
>
> `SingletonB` **is** `Singleton`

i.e. *they're both `Singleton`*

The expected meaning of `Singleton` means there can be only one. Many people from an OO background using your code will be confused.

Usually, implementation of Singleton would be on a per class basis because most OO languages will not be bent to allow the intent of what you are proposing.

That PHP might do (via `get_called_class()` magic) doesn't mean it should.

I can absolutely accept that from a utilitarian point of view, the accepted answer looks good. Given the niftyness of the accepted answer, I'd propose a name change that doesn't conflict with "standard" Singleton implementation. From a strict OO point of view, one could never inherit from a Singleton, so it really needs a different name.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond in such a generous manner. I won't claim much expertise when it comes to the theory behind the singleton pattern, but while I agree SingletonA and SingletonB can both be said to be instances of Singleton, they're also instances of distinct types. I haven't been able to find any definition addressing the inheritance aspect of the pattern, but the way I see it, is that if a jungle can hold only one tiger and one lion, they can both co-exist even if they're both felines. Again, I claim no greater knowledge of this than that of my own ravings.

Comment: I know what you mean here, and I wouldn't design something with multiple singletons anyway (I'd use one at most, and store all the other instances in that one).  I agree that it would be better (a) to rename the base class as `BaseSingleton` or something similar.